# Display png icon on exe file windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set a icon with a png format. I could achieve it on my forms, by those lines on the `public FormName()` function:

```
Bitmap bmp = ApplicationName.Properties.Resources.myicon;
this.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon());
```

However, when I release the application, I can't see the icon on the .exe file (I have the standard icon picture). How I can display the form's icon to be set also on the application.exe icon?

Comment: Explorer probably saw your program running before, but without this icon.  Google "reset shell icon cache" or rename your exe or try it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Open properties of your project in Visual Studio, and select your icon in the group "Icon and manifest" in the tab "Application".

Comment: It works only with an .ico file. I wants achieve it with .png file.

Comment: @WebR are there some problems to convert png to ico for SINGLE application icon? It seems that setting png  as application icon isn't now possible.

Comment: @WebR and anyway ico can internally store embedded PNG image (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format))).